# Align TextView inside ImageView in ReletiveLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get my `TextView` to be in the center of my `ImageView("SqureImageView")`. They both are in a `ReletiveLayout`, that is in a `LinearLayout`.

This is how it looks now:

[image]
'

The code of the `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
        <com.example.itay.sumika.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleWhosTurnIsIt"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cirecle_pink_new"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="67"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` might solve your
>   problem.

Try below code:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <com.example.itay.sumika.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleWhosTurnIsIt"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/cirecle_pink_new"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="67"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"  
        android:gravity="center"/>
```